# jquery in a usercontrol not being rendered on the page

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ascx

I'm stumped. I have this clip of jquery on a usercontrol but when I try to execute it I get "function undefined" I checked the rendered mark up and indeed the jquery is not there. What did I miss? I have tried several solutions from SOF but none have worked. This is a app with Master/Content pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function closeDataContainer() {
        $('div[id$=datacontainer]').hide('slow');
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Ok really bizarre. Using firebug the code is plainly there
[image]

and to show the error...
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by " I checked the rendered mark up and indeed the jquery is not there"? You mean the above code is not rendered on the page?

Comment: It sounds like you're having a caching issue.  Try clearing out your browser cache, closing your browser, and re-open it.  Does not sound like a JavaScript issue as the code is not even being rendered.

Comment: `datacontainer` is the last part of an id (according to his selector).

Comment: "... indeed the jQuery is not there." Do you mean jQuery itself? Or the script your wrote above?

Comment: that is correct the function is not rendered in the page. I opened the script document file that is created by VS and searched for the function and it's not there, nor is it there if I right click on the page and view source. 'datacontainer' is an id of a div.

Comment: FYI all javascript is functional on the master and content pages

Comment: Everything else is rendering?  Does it see the other functions?

Comment: No functions on that .ascx are able to be executed due to same problem.

Comment: Tim, from the markup in the HTML tab it looks like the function is rendered to me.  How and when are you actually attempting to call the function?  It is possible that when the call to closeDataContainer is made, the page hasn't finished loading and your javascript has not fully rendered.

Comment: I am calling the function from a OnClientClick method of an asp:button. so the page ia fully rendered by the time the function get called

Comment: Sorry I got pulled into another project for a little bit. I will post back when I have a chance to try debugging this issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are trying to call function before it is defined.

Comment: I have the call to the function in the OnClientClick event of the ASP:Button

Comment: see if you can invoke it via the Firefox console

Comment: it didn't throw an error trying to execute the function when it was placed in the masterpage. It didn't do what it was supposed to do but it didn't error.